# Order by value in Firebase Realtime Database

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to order by the value of **posicion** the products objects:

```
{
  "categorias" : {
    "productos" : {
      "0001-0001" : {
        "numero" : "0001-0001",
        "posicion" : 10
      },
      "0001-0002" : {
        "numero" : "0001-0002",
        "posicion" : 20
      },
      "0001-0003" : {
        "numero" : "0001-0003",
        "posicion" : 30
      },
      "0001-0004" : {
        "numero" : "0001-0004",
        "posicion" : 40
      },
      "0001-0005" : {
        "numero" : "0001-0005",
        "posicion" : 50
      },
      "0001-0006" : {
        "numero" : "0001-0006",
        "posicion" : 60
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I have read the firebase documentation but there is no example of this, there are only examples of orderByKey and orderByChild.

I would be very grateful if someone could help me.
Thanks

Comment: Is the JSON an export of your Realtime Database? What do you exactly mean by "entries on this **document**"?

Comment: Yes is a JSON exported from Firebase. I am referring to the different product objects.

Comment: I've posted an answer. Please let me know if you need more assistance, you can also click tick icon if satisfied so others know that issue is resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following code, it sorts the children in "productos" node based on the value of "posicion".

```
const db = firebase.database()
db.ref("categorias/productos").orderByChild("posicion").once("value").then((list) => {
  list.forEach((product) => {
    console.log(product.val())
  })
})
```

I tried it out with your sample JSON and here's the output:
[image]

`orderByChild()` sorts it in ascending order. If you need the list in descending order then you would have to do it using Javascript yourself.

PS: Please do not use `console.log(list.val())` directly as then the object won't appear to be sorted because your browser may reorder the keys of object in alphabetical order.

Therefore you should ideally run a forEach loop on the snapshot (list in this case).